# Best way to get the desired results in laravel query or eloquent way

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following schema :

[image: schema of of database table]

Where you can see that

```
1 category = multiple amenities,
1 amenities = multiple amenity_values
1 amenity_values = multiple units_amenities_values
multiple units_amenities_values = 1 units
```

**My requirements**

Need to find if more than 1 amenities from the same category falls to the same units and if there are two or multiple amenities from the same category inside the units. We need to create a bundle name like: `amenity1 - amenity2`.

To make it more clear, i have following data.

**Categories**

```
id |  category_name
1  |  CatA
2  |  CatB
```

**amenities**

```
id  |  amenity_name  | category_id
1   | Am1A           |  1
2   | Am2A           |  1
3   | Am1B           |  2
```

**amenity_values**

```
id  | amenity_value  | amenity_id
1   |  10            | 1
2   |  15            | 1
3   |  20            | 2
4   |  30            | 3
```

**units_amenities_values**

```
id  | amenity_value_id  | unit_id
1   | 1                 | 1
2   | 2                 | 2
3   | 3                 | 1
4   | 4                 | 3
```

**units**

```
id  | unit_number 
1   | 101
2   | 201
3   | 301
```

In this example, you can see that amenity: `Am1A` and `Am2A` both falls to the same category `CatA` and both of them are also in unit_number `101` So, in this case I need to get:

```
[
 [
  'unit_id'      => 1
  'category_id'   => 1
  'amenity_name' => 'Am1A - Am2A'
 ]
]
```

If you need any details, let me know.

Comment: Have you made plain SQL query for your request already?